# making a query using COUNT

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I want to have one table with many tables.
Before I put the `Count(taskid)`, it works well.

```
private DataTable GetData() //get any data
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=aa.net;Initial Catalog=db_c;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=db_c_ExternalWriter;Password=aa";
    string query = "Select a.Name, b.Restaurant,  a.City, c.[Postal Code], a.[Open Date], a.POSSystem FROM Stores a, tblConcepts b, tblStates c WHERE a.ConceptID = b.Restaurantid AND  a.State = c.Stateid AND a.[Open Date] >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime";
   // string query2 = "SELECT Count(Taskid) FROM tblAssignedTasks WHERE Complete = 'True' GROUP BY StoreID";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                comm.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = comm;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I add `Count(taskid)` it doesn't work.
 `SELECT Count(Taskid) FROM tblAssignedTasks WHERE Complete = 'True' GROUP BY StoreID;` I want to add these queries, any ideas?

```
private DataTable GetData() //get any data
{
    string connString = @"Data Source=aa.net;Initial Catalog=db_c;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=db_c_ExternalWriter;Password=aa";
    string query = "Select a.Name, b.Restaurant,  a.City, c.[Postal Code], a.[Open Date], a.POSSystem, d.Count(Taskid) FROM Stores a, tblConcepts b, tblStates c, tblAssignedTasks d WHERE a.ConceptID = b.Restaurantid AND  a.State = c.Stateid AND a.[Open Date] >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime AND b.Restaurantid = d.StoreID AND  d.Complete = 'True' GROUP BY d.StoreID)";
   // string query2 = "SELECT Count(Taskid) FROM tblAssignedTasks WHERE Complete = 'True' GROUP BY StoreID";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                comm.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = comm;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say _it doesn't work_, what exactly happens?  Throws exception, returns unexpected result, etc?

Comment: @LB2 I can't see the data for  the second query. Saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: Have you tested the query directly in SQL? Your problem appears to be a mis placed right parenthesis.

Comment: @Jacob H Yes the first one works well, and I want to add the Count(taskid) to the table, but I failed.

Comment: You need to close your first cast with a right parenthesis after datetime, and remove the one after the end of the statement. And add the necessary columns to the group by. Aggregates are all or nothing (all columns need grouped or aggregated, or none of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your query.
 when you are using aggregate function (`Count()`)   you must include all fields inside `GROUP BY` clause.
also,change the wrong syntax of that line `d.Count(Taskid) as 'taskKid'` (and give an alias name ) to  `Count(d.Taskid) as 'taskKid'` 
another fix: `a.[Open Date] >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime` **is wrong changed it to** `a.[Open Date] >= getdate()` 
this should work:

```
    SELECT a.Name, 
           b.Restaurant,  
           a.City, 
           c.[Postal Code], 
           a.[Open Date],
           a.POSSystem, 
           Count(d.Taskid) as 'taskKid' 
      FROM Stores a,
           tblConcepts b, 
           tblStates c, 
           tblAssignedTasks d 
     WHERE a.ConceptID = b.Restaurantid
       AND a.State = c.Stateid 
       AND a.[Open Date] >= getdate() 
       AND b.Restaurantid = d.StoreID 
       AND d.Complete = 'True' 
  GROUP BY a.Name,
           b.Restaurant,
           a.City, 
           c.[Postal Code], 
           a.[Open Date],
           a.POSSystem
```

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't work..and I just want to use GROUP BY for the below query. SELECT Count(Taskid) FROM tblAssignedTasks WHERE Complete = 'True'.  So I can have Count(Taskid) data when b.Restaurantid = d. StoreID.

Comment: @JacobH tnx, `a.[Open Date] >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime` is wrong changed it to `a.[Open Date] >= getdate()` . try it now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that query from what we can tell (you haven't included the DDL data so True may be an integer but we don't know). If you run the query in SQL what is the error that is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your sql Query with the below query,Hope it works fine.

```
string query = "Select COUNT(Taskid) OVER() Taskid, a.Name, b.Restaurant,  a.City, c.[Postal Code], a.[Open Date], a.POSSystem, d.Count(Taskid) FROM Stores a, tblConcepts b, tblStates c, tblAssignedTasks d WHERE a.ConceptID = b.Restaurantid AND a.State = c.Stateid AND a.[Open Date] >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime AND b.Restaurantid = d.StoreID AND  d.Complete = 'True' GROUP BY d.StoreID)";
```